# Pie chart using flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using Jquery Flot to create a pie chart based on three different values, pause, nopause and sleeping. Initially it draws th pie chart correctly but after some redraw it gives me the following error.

**Could not draw pie with labels contained inside canvas**

My code is

```
Lecturer.socket.onmessage = function (message) {

   var str = message.data;
   var msg = str.split(":");
   if(msg[0] == 'pause'){
       var pause = parseInt(msg[1]);
       var noPause = parseInt(msg[2]);
       var sleeping = parseInt(msg[3]);
       var data = [
          {label: "Pause", data:pause},
          {label: "No Pause", data:noPause},
          {label: "Sleeping", data:sleeping}
       ];
   var options = {
        series: {
            pie: {show: true}
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        }
     };

    $.plot($("#pie-placeholder"), data, options);
}
```

};

HTML is

```
<div id="live-placeholder" class="flot"></div>
```

All the require js libraries are included. What I m doing wrong? Any Help ?

Thanks

Comment: whenever i see "flot", i think it says "frot", ewww, which is something else in it's entirety...

Comment: Do you want to show pie percent or you are pointing something else?
Please check and verify my ans if it makes any sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two problems:

1.) your placeholder `div` id doesn't match the `$.plot` call.  `live-placeholder != pie-placeholder`.

2.) You don't need to calculate the percents yourself.  Flot will do it internally.

See a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LFm9m/).

Comment: So you mean I dont need to get the total of all values and divide each value by total and multiply it with 100 ?

Comment: @UmairIqbal yes exactly flot will do it for you